# Build checks not running while project is building in CCNet 1.5.6444.5

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I've just upgraded our CCNet installation to build 1.5.6444.5, and now while a build is running on one queue, none of the other build checks (on another queue) run at all until this build completes.

This was all working fine on 1.4.2.14. Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How have you got the ccnet.config file set-up, as isn't this related to the integration queues set up for each project?

Here's a web [link to a site](http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2007/07/02/CruiseControl.NET-1.3-and-Integration-Queues.aspx) that depicts the queues in action.

Does that help?